# Docker Pgadmin 4

Tags: docker, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

EDIT

**Turned out to a problem with the image, I tried another one and it works fine**

---

I'm trying to run Pgadmin 4 as server mode using Docker on Debian 9. I have followed the instructions on https://hub.docker.com/r/dpage/pgadmin4/  I start it by the following command

```
docker run -p 5050:5050 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=a12345678" -d  dpage/pgadmin4
```

I don't get any errors, and `docker ps` shows the status as below

```
root@poweredge:~# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                 CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                     NAMES
c4b11e4bceb7        dpage/pgadmin4      "/bin/bash /entry.sh"   12 seconds ago      Up 10 seconds       80/tcp, 443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->5050/tcp   upbeat_jackson
```

But when I go to serverip:5050 nothing loads. Any idea what the problem may be here?

On the local machine when I execute `curl http://localhost:5050` I get `Connection reset by peer` if the docker instance is running

```
root@poweredge:~# curl http://localhost:5050
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

if I stop the Docker instance, I get

```
root@poweredge:~# curl http://localhost:5050
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 5050: Connection refused
```

Comment: maybe you need to try `localhost:5050`?

Comment: @Arya which image you tried? Did you use the same port mapping while starting?

Answer (score 33):

PgAdmin 4 docker container has exposed port 80 and 443 by default. You can checck the Dockerfile here https://github.com/postgres/pgadmin4/blob/master/pkg/docker/Dockerfile

So the port mapping parameter in the command has to be updated (-p host_port: container_port)

Below is the updated command to access pgadmin4 via http (port 80)

`docker run -p 5050:80 -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=myemail@gmail.com" -e "PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=a12345678" -d  dpage/pgadmin4`

After starting the container you should be able to access it via http://localhost:5050

Comment: I had `admin` `admin` as user and password and didn't work on my mac (on Linux it worked) so I just change to a more complex user and password and worked:

`PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=test@example.com` and `ADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=test1234`

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to access it out side your virtual box? If yes, check if you have port forwarding rules of your Virtual machine set correctly:[image]

Comment: I'm on a Debian terminal. Is there anyway to test it inside the Docker vm with a command?

Comment: Turned out to a problem with the image, I tried another one and it works fine